# Call a data from a database in a .ini file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ini, labview

I have a little problem about my .ini file. I am using LabVIEW to pilot a Power Supply GPD-2303. And I have to configure the Voltage and the Current searched for each cards. These datas are in a Database but I have only a read access on it.

Voltage, Name, AlphaNumCode... Are not a problem because it will probably never change so my code is looking like:

```
[AlphaNumCode]
VSET_1=VALUE
VSET_2=VALUE
CSET_1=VALUE
CSET_2=VALUE
Assembly_PN=VALUE
```

That's to set Voltage, Current at the start of the execution on LabVIEW and give an Assembly PN "IF KQG then AssemblyPN= 1633".

That's the situation. The problem is there:

```
[Assembly PN]
CURRENT1_PROG_SEARCHED=VALUE
CURRENT2_PROG_SEARCHED=VALUE
CURRENT1_BLANK_SEARCHED=VALUE
CURRENT2_BLANK_SEARCHED=VALUE
```

I want to transform it, because if this value is not a fix value. I am looking for Something like:

```
[Assembly PN]
CURRENT1_PROG_SEARCHED="VALUE IN COLON W, LINE X"
CURRENT1_PROG_SEARCHED="VALUE IN COLON W, LINE X"
CURRENT2_PROG_SEARCHED="VALUE IN COLON X, LINE X"
CURRENT1_BLANK_SEARCHED="VALUE IN COLON Y, LINE X"
CURRENT2_BLANK_SEARCHED="VALUE IN COLON Z, LINE X"
```

I have found: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149090
But it show how to interact with the colon but not with a specific case. Is there a command?

That's the last thing I have to do in my Internship to end this project and I do not like let things unfinished.

Hope someone can help me or give me documents to learn how to do it, it will be great :)

Edit:

Yes, this article show how to access data by a text file, and the text file is linked to the data in the database, I was thinking that could work.

I am clearly new about database so I am sorry about the lack of knowledge I will try to do my best, but using SQL server and System DSN to Access it in LabVIEW. 
The ini File is read in a LabVIEW Program 
By"COLON" I mean "COLUMN

**Edit:**

I send you my Sub VI and a picture of my code, that's what I want. still having 2 days to end it so I hope you can read me guys!

```
[1630]LINE=WHERE (OC=1630);
[1631]LINE=WHERE (OC=1631);
[1632]LINE=WHERE (OC=1632);
[1633]LINE=WHERE (OC=1633);
[1635]LINE=WHERE (OC=1635);
```

[LabVIEW Picture of the Sub VI 25/07/16 using  DB Select Tool Kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtmSo.png)

Best regards,
Robin.

Comment: The article you have linked to is about accessing data in a text file as if it were a database table. Please clarify what you are actually trying to do: 1) where is the data you need to access - you say in 'a database', what kind of database? 2) where do you need to read this data into - a LabVIEW program? 3) what do you mean by 'colon' which is the symbol : - do you mean 'column'?

Comment: Sorry, I am new here so I do not know if I have to post an answer or a comment to answer to you Nekomatic. Thanks for your fast answer

Yes, this article show how to access data by a text file, and the text file is linked to the data in the database, I was thinking that could work.

1) Hm, I am clearly new about database so I am sorry about the lack of knowledge I will try to do my best, but using SQL server and System DSN to Access it in LabVIEW. 2) The ini File is read in a LabVIEW Program 3) Yes, I was meaning column.

Comment: You've done the right thing by replying to my comment with another comment, and also by editing your answer with the further information. The article shows how to make a *text file look like a database*, but your data is already in a database. I'm still not sure what you mean by *.ini file* - do you *also* have information in a file, or do you mean that the 'ini' settings for your program are part of the information in the database?

Comment: The best way to get data from a SQL Server database into LabVIEW is using the Database Connectivity Toolkit VI's, but these aren't included with the cheaper editions of LabVIEW so you need to check whether you have them or not. Is the use of SQL Server fixed or could you use a different database? Is the database on the same PC as the LabVIEW software or not?

Comment: Oh ok, that's not for my problem so, I am really looking evertwhere but well I find Nothing that looks like to my problem... I mean I am using a "setting.ini" and "current_waited.ini" I want to catch the current_waited 
I am using a Sub_VI to call the Configuration File in LabVIEW, and I want the data in the Configuration File, I can do it in LabVIEW by asking directly from Database, but that's not ok for futur users that don't need to use LabVIEW just add new "card type" setting in the configuration file.ini

Comment: Yes, I have no problem about Database Conectivity Toolkit VI's I have it, and I use it to Add datas from the test of the card. But that's not the way I want to use to call the data. In fact, someone can just add a new type of card and set datas from database, I want the user that don't modify my program to add a new type of card setting, just using a ini file then it can be easier for them to add a card. Please say me if I am not clear :-)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand exactly where the problem is. You can read values from a .ini file using LabVIEW's Configuration File VIs. You can read values from a database using the Database Connectivity VIs. You can use LabVIEW code to work out what to read and what to do with the result. Can you show a specific example of which part of this is not working? Include the data.

Comment: This way can work, I am trying to have another way to do this by only the .ini file

I am actually in internship, the guys do not know LabVIEW but they will have to change somethings, like add new type of cards to tests and I am searching a good way to give them the possibility to change it without using LabVIEW
It's really hard to explain... With the solution that you gave they will have to go in LabVIEW to write code "If AssemblyPN=XXXX, then the current searching is at line X, column Y."

Comment: I mean If there is a new type of card that they add to the Database, they will have to program in LabVIEW "where is the current searched?" -> At (Column, Line) to get the data.

With a .ini file they will just have to add it like:

[1800] //New type

Current1_Waited_PROG=0.6 //The current waited if the card is prog
Current1_Waited_BLANK=0.2//The current waited if the card is blank
...

Comment: The best way will be to ask in .ini to take the data value at the good line / good column, that's all. It is easier to them and to me for program it, then I can be sure if they want to edit they can do it without learn how to use LabVIEW.

Is there anyway to identifie the "case" where the data is in a .ini? That's for what I am looking for, I know they will change somethings, so easier it is to add things better the work is and the .ini file probably the easier way. 

Sorry for triple comment, just trying to explain what am I looking for and why your solution is not appropriate

Comment: LabVIEW gets the assembly number from the ini file, and the database record for each assembly includes the current values for that assembly number? So why can't LabVIEW run a query on the database, using the assembly number, to retrieve the current values?

Comment: It can as I said, it will be harder ti change if we have a new Assembly Number that come to the table in the future, it can be easier to just change that in the .ini file. But well it looks like impossible to call a data from a database in a .ini file...

Comment: I have found a solution but what condition I can use to pick the data at the right line? looking like it takes everytime the column name by using the DB Select Tool Kit, I want to create a condition to make it only when I have the exact Assembly Number.

For example: Assembly Number= 1633, condition= "WHERE OC=1633" or "AT LINE= 32" I attached the code VI + picture. It smell good

Comment: Sorry for 3rd post, I find the problem, my column have special characters, that is not supported on LabVIEW, I do not have the rights on the table. how to avoid this? using "", '', [] do not work.

I will send the solution after solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, in fact I am using a .ini file to send a condition:

Just to know: (OC = Assembly Number)

In my .ini I have:

[1633]
OC=WHERE(OC=1633);

Then I send it to the condition in DB Select Tool Kit and I enter the column / table where is the data I am looking for.

Then if a new card need to be test they just need to make a new line in the .ini file:

[XXXX]
OC=WHERE(OC=XXXX);

Thanks for your help that problem is resolve, I hope it can help someone that want to make communication between LabVIEW / .ini / Database

Best regards,
Robin